# Calling an objects methods based off of an object of the same type

Tags: php

I'm working on a basic quest/achievement system.  I have a class that we'll call questManager.  The way I determine completion of the quest is by comparing an Action object to a Quest object.  The questManager holds an array of Action objects that are not yet complete.

The standard action utilization looks something like this:  $actionObject->used()->item(itemID)-on()->user(userID);

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to take that object, pass it to the quest manager and apply the methods that were called along with passed arguments to all of the action objects within the quest manager's incomplete action array?

I know I could simply build an array of methods that were called along with arguments provided.  I'm just not sure if there's something native in PHP for this type of situation.  I've read over reflections but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.  Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In looking through the PHP documentation, I found a MethodLog class that someone wrote that utilizes the __call magic method.  Essentially, it logs all function calls with passed arguments into an array.  You may then pass an object into the replay method of the MethodLog class.  It loops over the passed in object and calls all of the logged functions from the passed in object.

So I return a MethodLog object, call the applicable functions $methodLog->used()->item(itemID) etc., and then pass the MethodLog object into my quest manager.  The quest manager iterates over all of my actions and calls the functions on each action object that the MethodLog called!

Pretty neat find and kudos to the person who thought that one up.